# Expansion work of monatomic gas

Tags: thermodynamics, work, ideal-gas, gas

Monatomic ideal gas takes up Q heat, while its volume increases but the pressure stays the same.
How many %s of the heat is for expansion work?

I think it is an isobar process but how should I calculate?
The books says, that the answer is W'Q = 40% but I do not know how to get this solution.

Comment: Hi Joshi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the convention that $\Delta W$ is the work done by the system,

1st law of thermodynamics states:

$$\Delta Q=\Delta U+\Delta \tag{1}W$$

Now, for ideal gas undergoing isobaric process:

$$\Delta W=P \Delta V=n R \Delta T\tag{2}$$

For monoatomic ideal gas:

$$\Delta U= \frac{3}{2} n R \Delta T\tag{3}$$
 Combining (1), (2) and (3) one gets:
$$\Delta Q=\frac{5}{2}n R \Delta T=\frac{5}{2} P \Delta V\implies\frac{\Delta W}{\Delta Q}=\frac{2}{5} \text{or}\; 40\%$$